# Paypal webhook events never shows on log

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm currently working on paypal sandbox enviroment. My web app based on nodejs is able to successfully create a new paypal sale and process the data. My problem take place when there is no webhook event related to the new sale even when it was all ok and it's logged into **paypal-facilitator** balance.

I already follow the [paypal webhook integration guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/webhooks/rest-webhooks/) and I am able to receive notifications with mock webhook simulator.

Comment: I too have the exact same issue as you. I have a successfully create a new paypal sale but I am never receiving a webhook event that relates to that sale. I am however able to recieve notifications with the mock webhook simulator. As interesting thing I noticed is when I try to go and save the Sandbox weebhook URL in the paypal dashboard I am presented with a `Response statusCode (400) did not match expected (200)` even though that particular URL works when accessing it in my browser / postman / curl etc

Comment: Same issue to me, even the status code response. I received once notifications but in a delayed time (create a new sale yesterday, get notification today), I already set the correct timezone and still having the same issue. That was a particular time, because I've created new sales and no notifications were receive.